# Are there any non-trivial mathematical hypotheses that cannot be disproved by counterexample?

Tags: solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

*Proving* a hypothesis often requires the development of new and powerful techniques and maybe even new branches of mathematics.

However disproving such a hypothesis could result from a single counterexample.

Are there any *existing* *non-trivial* mathematical hypotheses that cannot, even in principle, be disproved by counterexample?

**Note**

By existing, I mean that have been published or discussed in reputable mathematical journals.

By non-trivial, I mean hypotheses that are not explicitly designed for the purpose of not being susceptible to counterexample.

Comment: "For all sufficiently large $n$, $2n$ is the sum of two primes".

Comment: @lulu - surely you could could find a counterexample by exhaustive search on a particular 2n

Comment: But it wouldn't matter, because that would just prove that your example wasn't "sufficiently large".

Comment: Maybe it would be clearly to you if it was phrased, equivalently, as "there are only finitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $2n$ is not the sum of two primes."

Comment: What is your definition of sufficiently large?

Comment: "all but finitely many $n$".

Comment: @lulu  -  Hmm, I see. Can you suggest a modification to my question that excludes deliberately formulated stumbling blocks?  P.S. I am not a mathematician.

Comment: There's nothing odd or forced about my example.  Lots of interesting results in number theory have a small (finite) list of exceptions. Note, of course, you could disprove my hypothesis by giving an infinite list of examples (if, say, you were able to prove that $2\times 10^k$ was never expressible as the sum of two primes). But you will need an infinite list.

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710950/prove-that-a-counterexample-exists-without-knowing-one is what you actually are looking for.

Comment: Existence-Theorems can usually not be disproven by counterexample. Say e.g. you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then the statement "There is an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x) = 0$" can not be disproven by counterexample. Actually only theorems which make statements about **every** object of some type can be disproven by counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Working in ZFC,

The Continuum Hypothesis is a famous example.

That there is no set with Cardinality greater than the naturals, and less than the Reals.